# SQL Trigger inside Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a User model in my django application project and I also created an email activation system, so when the user create an accaout, a message is sent to his mail. Inside this message there is a link with a token which has expire time = 1 day. When user click the link, `is_active` field inside User record turn into `true`, but if not, there will be an unactive user inside database forever.

For this reason I need to create a triegger which will delete the User record after one day if `is_active != true`. How can I create so trigger in Django model?

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
     ...
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
     is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     ...


     def __str__(self):
         return self.email
    
     def __getitem__(self,key):
         return self.__dict__[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way:

1. Create a Django command. Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

- Sample: check_user_inactive.py

```
... 
   def handle(self, *args, **options):
      qs = User.objects.filter(active != True)
      qs = qs.filter(...) # include your logic to filter who are not active in the past day. 
      qs.delete()
```

2. Write a bash shell to exec this command. `start.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
cd your-project-path
python manage.py check_user_inactive
```

3. Set up a cronjob to exec this command every 5 minutes or 15 minutes or 1 hour or a particular time you want. You can use `crontab` to do that.

```
1. sudo chmod +x `start.sh`
2. sudo crontab -e
3. edit file cron > */5 * * * * /your-path/start.sh
```

---

Or another professional way is to use Celery + Celery-beat to do that
Ref: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html